# Default option in drop-down menu

Tags: mysql, jinja2, webapp2, google-cloud-sql

I've just inherited a project and need help.  Using webapp2/jinja2/mysql(CloudSQL), how would you define the default option of a drop-down menu created by a database?

Example DB output:

```
SELECT * FROM tblNames;

Name_PK   Name
1         Alice
2         Bob
```

Example code:

```
<tr class="contactformblock">
  <td align="right">Name</td>
    <td> 
        <select name="Contact_Name">
        {% for state in stategroup %}
        <option value="{{ name[0] }}">{{ name[1] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>               
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Under current conditions, it goes alphabetically.  On the page, I'd rather it default the dropdown to Bob (who isn't at the top of the list).

Comment: What is the criteria for which option should be the default? You need something in the database to distinguish it.

Comment: That's pretty much what we've got to work with.  In this case, Bob would always be the default.

Another example of how this would be used is (reading the code) is states with their abbreviations being their PK.  The page loads with the drop-down sitting on Alaska; having it start on a state like New York would be better.

Comment: So you just want to hard-code the default, not determine it from anything algorithmic?

Comment: Correct.  Simple hard coding is all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this...

```
    <select name="Contact_Name">
    {% for state in stategroup %}
    {% if name[1] == 'Bob' %}
    <option value="{{ name[0] }}" selected>{{ name[1] }}</option>
    {% else %}
    <option value="{{ name[0] }}">{{ name[1] }}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Finally sat down to do this and it worked.  Thank you!